# Removing videotitle from vitamio player

Tags: android, vitamio

I use `vitamio player` (version 5.0.0) for playing some videos in my android app. And video title is shown on the bottom of screen during video playing. How I can remove this text from screen or change it?

And second question - how to add buttons forward and backward in `vitamio player` controller? Because there are only button play/stop and seekBar. Thanks.

Comment: Post your Coding here. Normally, Media controller auto hide.

Comment: You need to use your custom media controller to next/prev button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide video title in Vitamio in android (this will work if you have imported library instead of including jar), open **vitamio->res->layout->mediacontroller.xml** and set textview **mediacontroller_file_name**'s visibility to **INVISIBLE.**